# How do I make Dreamweaver to show me closing tags?

Tags: tags, syntax-highlighting, dreamweaver

I would like Dreamweaver to show me the opening/closing tag when I select a tag. This functionality is seen in many editors, I know for sure Eclipse has it.

To make things clearer: When I select/highlight a `<div>` opening tag with my mouse I would like Dreamweaver to select/highlight the `</div>` closing tag.

**My main questions:**

1. Does anybody know what this functionality is called?
2. Does anybody know how to add this functionality to Dreamweaver?

I've tried searching the Dreamweaver extensions on the Adobe exchange but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 26):

Dreamweaver has two different ways of selecting matching tags, depending on whether you're working with HTML or a scripting language.

To select the matching opening and closing tags of an HTML element, click inside the element, and click the Select Parent Tag button in the Coding toolbar. It's the sixth button from the top (I tried to attach a screenshot, but don't yet have sufficient privileges to do so).

To select matching opening and closing curly braces, brackets, or parentheses, click inside the opening or closing symbol, and click the Balance Braces button on the Coding toolbar (it's immediately below Select Parent Tag). Alternatively, use the keyboard shortcut, Ctrl+'/Cmd+'.

---

[image: Here's what the toolbar icons look like.]

Comment: Hi David, thanks for answer. It partially helped me. I must say I never used the coding tooblar functionality altough I always work in code view. I found the Balance Brace button but I don't get how it works. I'm in the opening symbol, click the brace button.... nothing happens/shows. Besudes that, do you know of a way to automate this. So that when I select a tag it automatically shows me the closing tag.

Comment: The Keyboard shortcut notation confused the hell out of me, its Ctrl AND ' OR Cmd AND '

Answer (score 5):

well I dont know If Im really giving u a solution but if u select a tag, the code editor will show u (at the end of the window) the tag u are on. If u click on the tag information (same place) then the code-editor will highlight the place in btw the choosen-tag

Answer (score 3):

I have to echo the sentiments of Ahmet Sali in saying that its a shame that Dreamweaver does not support the functionality of highlighting the beginning and end tags. This should be very simple. I became accustomed to this feature in Visual Studio and found it very useful.

Answer (score 2):

I think Dreamweaver doest it better than All other Editors.
You just need to see the Small Vertical Toolbar on the Left of the Line-numbers and search for 'Balance Braces' (highlights between { and } AND 'Select Parent Tag' (Highlights all inside parent-element ).

For HTML Tag Highlighting , again , just see the Small Horizontal bar' on the Bottom (also called Status Bar).

Whenever you select a HTML Tag, it automatically creates its Hierarchy in the shape of Small-Buttons. If you just Click on any Tag (or small-button) , then it highlights that Element upto the Matching Element.

Comment: This however is a good solution. But requires a lot of user activity like selecting the parent block, then clicking on the 'Balance Braces'. Adding a visual aid like line to connect on braces would be a better option such that by looking into the code we know which one ends where.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Dreamweaver has this option. The only way is to just go what David Powers says. You would have to click within the braces and click on the symbol. This would highlight the whole text from beginning of the brace to the end. If it doesn't do anything then that means there no ending or beginning. I'm using both dreamweaver and notepad++ and notepad++ does exactly that.