# Opening and closing tag highlighting in Dreamweaver

Tags: dreamweaver, notepad++

Is there a standard feature or plugin for Dreamweaver CS5 that allows tag highlighting like in Notepad++?

When you click on a tag in Notepad++, the opening and closing tags are both highlighted, and there is a red, vertical, dotted line between them.  I find this really handy especially when dealing with large XML documents.

Does anyone know of any way of enabling this feature in Dreamweaver?

Left: Notepad++, Right: Dreamweaver CS5
[image]

Comment: Didn't you ask this the other day?

Comment: Yes, but I got no answers and wanted to phrase it better.  I've deleted the other question.

Comment: Ah, no wonder I can't find it now.

Comment: Very observant of you. Do you have an answer?

Comment: Nope :( I haven't touched Dreamweaver in ages, and I'm not on CS5.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make Dreamweaver to show me closing tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606429/how-do-i-make-dreamweaver-to-show-me-closing-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really an equivalent way to do this in Dreamweaver.  The closest method is to use the Tag Selector while in any view (Split View works best, IMO) to pick the tag and highlight both it and its contents.

[image: Illustration of the Tag Selector]